# How do you calculate complexity of sum of factorials?

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, factorial

I am trying to understand how to calculate complexity.
I have this code of calculating the sum of factorials. I can tell by looking at it that its complexity is O(N^2). But I am not sure what is the polinome that was reduced to N^2 and how to calculate it.

```
    static int product1toN(int N)
    {
        if (!validateN(N))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            product *= i;
        }
        return product;
    }

    static int sumOfProducts(int N)
    {
        if (!validateN(N))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int sum=0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            sum += product1toN(i);
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you've got a loop within a loop, so for every N, you do it N times (n squared). What are you looking for?

Comment: `sumOfProducts` has `O(n^2)` time complexity. Current `sumOfProducts` implementation is in fact nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have `O(N^2)` time complexity for `sumOfProducts(int N)`. To see this, let's *inline* `product1toN`:

```
static int sumOfProducts(int N)
{
    if (!validateN(N))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int sum=0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        // static int product1toN(int N) inlined
        int product = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        {
            product *= j; // <- this line will be executed N * N times
        }

        sum += product;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

We have typical *nested loops* and `O(N * N) = O(N ^ 2)` time complexity. You can implement a better code:

```
// Factorial grows very fast; you may want BigInteger instead of int
static int sumOfProducts(int N) {
  if (!validateN(N))
    return -1;

  int sum = 0;
  int product = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) 
    sum += (product *= i); 

  return sum;
}
```

Here we have just ine simple loop and `O(N)` time complexity.